# Knockout.js reset the value of a select back to its default value when if another select is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am working on a Data Table that is populated 1 of 3 ways. 
1. Live Search
2. Select box 1 (searchCategory)
3. Select box 2 (searchTCA)

I have everything working except for one issue that I am unable to figure out.

When the user selects one of the options in either select box, I would like the other one to reset to default.

I am still learning knockout, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You-

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
     <form id="requestForm" class="request-form form-horizontal">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="searchInput" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Search</label>
             <div class="col-sm-9">
                 <input id="searchInput" type="text" name="searchInput" class="form-control" placeholder="What are you looking for?" onfocus="this.value=''" data-bind="textInput: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off" />
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="searchCategory" class="col-sm-3 control-label">View by Category</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select id="searchCategory" data-bind="options: availableCategories, value: selectedCategory, optionsCaption: 'Search by Category'"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="searchTCA" class="col-sm-3 control-label">View by TCA Method</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select id="searchTCA" data-bind="options: availableTcaMethods, value: selectedTcaMethod, optionsCaption: 'Search by TCA Method'"></select>
            </div>
       </div>
   </form>
 </div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
 define(function (require) {
"use strict";

var $ = require("jquery"),
    ko = require("knockout"),
    komapping = require("komapping"),
    bootstrap = require("bootstrap"),
    $embedElement = $("#Architectural-Guidebook");


if ($embedElement.length) {

    function ArchitecturalGuidebookViewModel(dduration) {
        var self = this;

        self.specifications = ko.observableArray([]);
        debugger;

        self.availableCategories = ko.observable();
        self.selectedCategory = ko.observable();

        self.availableTcaMethods = ko.observable();
        self.selectedTcaMethod = ko.observable();

        self.availableCategories = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            var types = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.specifications(), function (item) { return item.Category; });
            return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(types).sort();
        });

        self.availableTcaMethods = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            var types = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.specifications(), function (item) { return item.TcaMethod; });
            return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(types).sort();
        });

        self.specifications($.parseJSON(window.jsonModel));

        self.query = ko.observable('What are you looking for?');

        // Search
        self.pageNumber = ko.observable(0);
        self.filterSpecifications = ko.computed(function () {
            self.pageNumber(0);
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.specifications(), function (i) {
                var filterLogic =
                    (i.TcaMethod.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query().toLowerCase()) >= 0) ||
                    (i.Title.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query().toLowerCase()) >= 0) ||
                    (i.Category.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query().toLowerCase()) >= 0) ||
                    (i.Application.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query().toLowerCase()) >= 0) ||
                    (i.Category === self.selectedCategory() && self.query('What are you looking for?')) ||
                    (i.TcaMethod === self.selectedTcaMethod() && self.query('What are you looking for?'));
                return filterLogic;
            });
        });

        // Pagination
        self.nbPerPage = 8;
        self.totalPages = ko.computed(function () {
            var div = Math.floor(self.filterSpecifications().length / self.nbPerPage);
            div += self.filterSpecifications().length % self.nbPerPage > 0 ? 1 : 0;
            return div - 1;
        });

        self.paginated = ko.computed(function () {
            var first = self.pageNumber() * self.nbPerPage;
            return self.filterSpecifications().slice(first, first + 
                      self.nbPerPage);
        });

        self.hasPrevious = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.pageNumber() !== 0;
        });

        self.hasNext = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.pageNumber() !== self.totalPages();
        });

        self.next = function () {
            if (self.pageNumber() < self.totalPages()) {
                self.pageNumber(self.pageNumber() + 1);
            }
        };

        self.previous = function () {
            if (self.pageNumber() !== 0) {
                self.pageNumber(self.pageNumber() - 1);
            }
        };

    };

    ko.applyBindings(new ArchitecturalGuidebookViewModel());

  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`subscribe`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to the `selectedCategory` and `selectedTcaMethod` observables and set the other dropdown's value to `undefined` when one of them changes.

Also, you are clearing the input's `value` on `focus`. This will only clear the input and not `query` observable's value. So, `filterSpecifications` computed property doesn't get triggered `onfocus` even though the input is cleared. Instead, you could use the [`event`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) binding to call a function `onfocus`.

Here's a minimal working snippet:

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.selectedCategory = ko.observable();
  self.selectedTcaMethod = ko.observable();

  self.availableCategories = ko.observableArray(["Category 1"]);
  self.availableTcaMethods = ko.observableArray(["TCA 1"]);

  self.selectedCategory.subscribe(function() {
    // if condition added to avoid cyclic subscribe triggers
    if (self.selectedCategory())
      self.selectedTcaMethod(undefined);
  })
  self.selectedTcaMethod.subscribe(function() {
    // if condition added to avoid cyclic subscribe triggers
    if (self.selectedTcaMethod())
      self.selectedCategory(undefined);
  });

  self.query = ko.observable('What are you looking for?');

  self.onFocus = function() {
    // clear the input on focus
    self.query('');
  };

  self.filterSpecifications = ko.computed(() => {
    self.query() + self.selectedCategory() + self.selectedTcaMethod();
    console.log("computed");
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="textInput: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup', event: { focus: onFocus }" type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />

<select id="searchCategory" data-bind="options: availableCategories, value: selectedCategory, optionsCaption: 'Search by Category'"></select>

<select id="searchTCA" data-bind="options: availableTcaMethods, value: selectedTcaMethod, optionsCaption: 'Search by TCA Method'"></select>
```

Comment: Thank You- I am now getting the following error in the console. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at new ArchitecturalGuidebookViewModel (main.js:3357)
    at main.js:3452
    at Object.execCb (require.js:7)
    at S.check (require.js:7)
    at S.enable (require.js:7)
    at Object.enable (require.js:7)
    at S.<anonymous> (require.js:7)
    at require.js:7
    at v (require.js:7)
    at S.enable (require.js:7)

Comment: Also, need it to clear the selectboxes if users click on the input for searching. How would I integrate this?

Comment: @JonNowak Did you add `self.selectedCategory.subscribe()` part after `self.selectedCategory = ko.observable()` is defined?

Comment: The error is now gone. When testing, and I use a select box, the other is not resetting. However the console is showing that it is working.

Comment: So after looking again, it is actually resetting, the dropdown however is not going back to the default value. And when I click on the input to search, the selectboxes are not resetting either.

Comment: I am actually refering to the optionsCaption to be replaced when its is undefined..